# Stack entire column for table in CSS

Tags: html, css, responsive-design, html-table

Is there a way in CSS to stack an entire column so if my desktop table was the following:

```
| H1 | H2 | H3 | H4 |
| A1 | B1 | C1 | D1 |
| A2 | B2 | C2 | D2 |
```

It would turn into this for mobile:

```
| H1 |
| A1 |
| A2 |
| H2 |
| B1 |
| B2 |
| H3 |
| C1 |
| C2 |
| H4 |
| D1 |
| D2 |
```

I hope this makes sense

Here is my html structure:

```html
    <table class="rds-table">
    <tr>
        <th>H1</th>
  <th>H2</th>
  <th>H3</th>
  <th>H4</th>
 </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>A1</td>
        <td>B1</td>
        <td>C1</td>
        <td>D1</td>
    </tr>
 <tr>
  <td>A2</td>
  <td>B2</td>
  <td>C2</td>
     <td>D2</td>
 </tr>
 <tr>
  <td>A3</td>
  <td>B3</td>
  <td>C3</td>
  <td>D3</td>
 </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: Are you using a standard table markup with `tr` tags and so on?

Comment: Yeah I will make a JS fiddle 1 second.

Comment: You might need some clever jQuery/JavaScript...

Comment: Try this: https://css-tricks.com/responsive-data-tables/

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/tgxgvgnx/

Comment: @im1dermike i need ie8 support

Comment: Is the use of tables a must? This would be pretty easy to accomplish with [Bootstrap](http://getbootstrap.com) and would work in IE8.

Comment: seems best way to rewrite it on a `div` structure

Comment: Damn, was trying to keep it as simple as possible in terms of markup - I might need to go the JS route

Comment: If you use Bootstrap you don't need to use any JS to accomplish this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
.column {
    float:left;
}

.element {
    display: block;
    float:left;
    clear:both;
}

@media (max-width: 980px) {
    .column {
        clear:both;
    }
}


<div class="rds-table">
    <div class="column">
        <div class="element">Header One</div>
        <div class="element">Data One</div>
        <div class="element">Data One</div>
    </div>
    <div class="column">
        <div class="element">Header Two</div>
        <div class="element">Data Two</div>
        <div class="element">Data Two</div>
    </div>
</div>
```

The media query will look for the screen size of 980 or lower. Edit: There is updated code now, this will use divs instead of table elements.

Comment: This solution doesn't really work if there is a header, right?

Comment: Also, is the `display: block;` necessary?  Doesn't appear to be.

Comment: You're looking to have the tr elements overlap. I don't think this will be possible with the HTML you have.

Comment: You'll want think in terms of columns. H1, A1, A2 is one column, H1, B2, B3 is another. When the screen is normal size, the columns float left, clear none. When the screen size is smaller, the columns float left, clear both.  Edit: http://jsfiddle.net/tgxgvgnx/4/ Working link. Play with the width of the .elements for making it more uniform. Also test the max-width so you can understand it.

Comment: I'm trying to do it this way but for some reason my columns wont stretch to 100% in Desktop mode

http://jsfiddle.net/7sqkgfuh/3/

Comment: In case table cells have different height, rows are mis-aligned.

Answer (score 0):

In your css use @media to query for the screen size and organize contents in flex layout.

```js
$(window).on('resize', function() {
  myfunction();
});
$(document).ready(function() {
  $(window).trigger('resize');
});

function myfunction() {
  if (window.matchMedia('(max-width: 880px)').matches) {
    if (!$(".th").length) {
      $(".rds-table tbody").children().each(function(index) {
        console.log(index + ": " + $(this).prop("tagName"));
        if (index > 0) { //si nos brincamos el header y vamos a los demás tr

          $(this).prepend('<td class="th">' + $(".rds-table tr th:nth-child(" + index + ")").text() + '</td>');
          $(".rds-table tr th:nth-child(" + index + ")").addClass("invisible");

        }
      });
    }
  } else {

    /*       $(".th").addClass("invisible");*/
    $(".th").remove();
    $(".invisible").removeClass("invisible");
  }
}
```

```css
    @media (max-width: 880px) {

      td {

        display: flex;

      }

    }

    .th {

      color: blue;

    }

    .invisible {

      display: none;

    }

    th,

    td {

      border: 1px;

      border-style: dashed;

      border-color: gray;

    }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table class="rds-table">
  <tr>
    <th>Header One</th>
    <th>Header Two</th>
    <th>Header Three</th>
    <th>Header Four</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Data One H1</td>
    <td>Data Two H1</td>
    <td>Data Three H1</td>
    <td>Data Four H1</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Data One H2</td>
    <td>Data Two H2</td>
    <td>Data Three H2</td>
    <td>Data Four H2</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Data One H3</td>
    <td>Data Two H3</td>
    <td>Data Three H3</td>
    <td>Data Four H3</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Data One H4</td>
    <td>Data Two H4</td>
    <td>Data Three H4</td>
    <td>Data Four H4</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

As you can appreciate borders are perfect when you use Jquery, but when you use css only it can create subtle errors (compare fiddles [My fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/javatlacati/zvhb8Ly9/) and [Brendan's fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/javatlacati/5L30d9k3/)).